# C# CefSharp is not saving or loading any caches

Tags: c#, caching, save, load, cefsharp

I cannot save or load the cache data from my CefSharp browser application.

I tried adding `cefSet.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("renderer-process-limit", "1");` after seeing it got suggested alot, same with `cefSet.CachePath = //cache directory as string` non of them worked, i personally believe that it might be connected to another problem im having which is cef always thinking that its already initialized even after i just open the computer and program can't start without i put this part to the code:

```
if (Cef.IsInitialized == false)
        {
            Cef.Initialize(cefSet, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
        }
```

Which means its possibly never initialising, but at the same logically it can't open without initialising when the pc just got open. But since there is no confirmation on initialising being the the exact problem i wanted to ask in a rather open way.

```
//created chromiumWebBrowser1 on the form

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings cefSet = new CefSettings();
        cefSet.CachePath = curDir + @"\cch";
        cefSet.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("renderer-process-limit", "1");
        if (Cef.IsInitialized == false)
        {
            Cef.Initialize(cefSet, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
        }
        chromiumWebBrowser1.Controls.Add(browser);
    }

    public static string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    public static string gameLoc = "file:///" + curDir + "/test.html";
    public static ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(gameLoc,new RequestContext());

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
```

I expected some cache files in my folder as im using the application and after using it. tried with few sites and nothing on cache so far.

Comment: Render process limit is not recommended generally speaking, best not to change the process limit.You must call Cef.Initialize before creating your first ChromiumWebBrowser instance. Your static instance is being created long before the form is loaded.

Comment: To keep things clear and simple I usually recommend calling Cef.Initialize in program main see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs for an example

Comment: @amaitland i did move `Cef.Initialize` and few other needed things to main but it didn't make a difference, im slowly starting to thing that the issue is my computer rather than the program.

Comment: Test with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample it's very unlikely a problem with your computer

Comment: yes, this is working, thank you, I can dissect this to solve my problem.